# Pass parameter to jest.mock

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a mock as follows

```
jest.mock('react-hook-inview', () => {
  const setRef = jest.fn();
  const observer = jest.fn();
  const intersecting = true;
  const entry = {
    y: 0,
  };
  return [setRef, intersecting, entry, observer];
});
```

Here I would like to change the `intersecting` value. How can I change that from one test to another? I was trying to use something like a factory:

```
const inView = (intersecting) => {
  jest.mock('react-hook-inview', () => {
    const setRef = jest.fn();
    const observer = jest.fn();
    const entry = {
      y: 0,
    };
    return [setRef, intersecting, entry, observer];
  });
}
```

and use it like

```
  it('is invisible by default', () => {
    const text = 'Test';
    const { container } = render(<Reveal>{text}</Reveal>);
    inView(false);
    expect(container.firstChild).not.toBeVisible();
  });

  it('is visible when in view', () => {
    const text = 'Test';
    const { container } = render(<Reveal>{text}</Reveal>);
    inView(true);
    expect(container.firstChild).toBeVisible();
  });
```

however this throws

```
The module factory of `jest.mock()` is not allowed to reference any out-of-scope variables.
Invalid variable access: intersecting
```

does anybody have an idea?

cheers!

### EDIT:

My solution for now is to mock it like this

```
import ReactHookInview from 'react-hook-inview';

jest.mock('react-hook-inview', () => ({
  useInView: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    const setRef = jest.fn();
    const observer = jest.fn();
    const intersecting = false;
    const entry = {
      boundingClientRect: {
        y: 0,
      },
    };
    return [setRef, intersecting, entry, observer];
  }),
}));
```

and in my test I overwrite like this:

```
ReactHookInview.useInView.mockImplementation(() => {
  const setRef = jest.fn();
  const observer = jest.fn();
  const intersecting = true;
  const entry = {
    boundingClientRect: {
      y: 1,
    },
  };
  return [setRef, intersecting, entry, observer];
});
```

but that's not really beautiful

Comment: You left `const intersecting = true` in the function which masks passed parameter `intersecting`. I don't think this will fix your issue though as jest hoists module mocks.

Comment: @DrewReese I doubt it as Jest doesn't allow closure style references to variables. This is probably because Jest hoists mocks.

Comment: @DrewReese good eye! unfortunately I just left this here but didn't make this mistake in my actual code :D I also updated my initial post

Answer (score 2):

You can mock your library as you have already done, import it and explicitly set it's value. And then before have two different sets of tests:

```
jest.mock('react-hook-inview', /* as above */ );

import rhi from 'react-hook-inview';

describe('my implementation', () => {

  describe('while intersecting', () => {
    let result;
    beforeAll(() => {
      rhi[1] = true;
      result = myImplementationUsingIntersecting();
    });

    it('should result X', () => {
      expect(result).toEqual(X);
    });
  });

  describe('while NOT intersecting', () => {
    let result;
    beforeAll(() => {
      rhi[1] = false;
      result = myImplementationUsingIntersecting();
    });

    it.todo('should result Y');
  });
})
```

[working example](https://repl.it/repls/DarkgrayJuicyAmoeba)

**Edit 2: in order to properly mock a React hook**

since the react hooks are functions that return stuff you'll can mock it like this

```
jest.mock('react-hook-inview', () => jest.fn());
// and you can take it's reference with import
import useInView from 'react-hook-inview';
// and then you can mock it's return value as array
beforeAll(() => {
  useInView.mockReturnValue(['a', true, 'b', 'c']);
  result = myImplementationUsingIntersecting();
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried to adapt your solution. For example I had to use `const [setRef, intersecting, entry, observer] = rhi.useInView();` and of course change `myImplementationUsingIntersecting` with the implementation mentioned above, but it doesn't work. Also I don't understand why this would be supposed to work? I mean if I change the value of the destructured `intersecting` in my `beforeAll` hook.. why should my implementation use that? And I guess that's also not the case.

Comment: @MarcMintel sorry, my answer was just a solution outline I haven't tested it, but now I've updated it and I've added working example

Comment: @MarcMintel so basically `jest.mock` is returning an array and you can modify it's `[1]` property which is the `intersecting` that will be used in the implementation

Comment: thanks for your explanation! That makes a lot more sense to me. However I still don't get it to work. Maybe that's because `rhi` is not returning an array but an object with `useInView` method that's returning an array? But I also tried to change `rhi.useInView[1]` without success.

Comment: Thanks! That's very similar to my "current workaround". What I don't like about this solution is, that I have to know about each single value of the return. If I could pass a true or false as a parameter it would make things much more easy.. or maybe call a method that changes the intersecting value. For example I would also have to change the `y` value of `entry.boundingClientRect` and here things start getting a little bit too complex to change the values in each test.